# C# mv5 pass parameter through link then get it in view

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5

how to get the pass parameter in my view. 
i passed a parameter using

```
 <td>
<a  href="@Url.Action("report", "Map" , new { id = "Inventory"})" target="_blank"> Inventory Reports</a>
</td>
```

in my controller

```
public ActionResult report()
        {

            return View();
        }
```

../Map/report/Inventory

the url is already showing the pass data but how can i get it in jquery or javascript

Comment: I think you're used `public ActionResult report(string id)` (id = URL parameter). What you expect afterwards when controller returns the view?

Comment: i just need to get the pass value in javascript .

Comment: Use ViewBag/ViewData & put into JS like this: `var id = '@ViewBag.Id'` (or use a viewmodel).

Comment: thanks that works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a parameter from your route you can pass it from your controller back to the page via a view model or just the viewbag if that's all you have:

```
public ActionResult report(string id)
{
  ViewBag.id = id;
  return View();
}
```

In your view you can write the value to a hidden input

```
@Html.Hidden("id", ViewBag.id)
```

Then in your JavaScript you can read the id value and use it as you like

```
var id = document.getElementsByName("id")[0].value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the lastIndexOf() function to locate the last occurrence of the / character in your URL, then the substr() function to return the substring starting from that location:

```
var value =this.href.substring(this.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

```js
alert(window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1))
```